# Instances on the same (non-default) network -- firewall rules for intra-network traffic?

Tags: networking, firewall

I'm having the following problem:

Within GCE, I defined a custom (i.e. non-default) network (+prefix) to be used by my instances.

According to this document https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/networking#firewalls_1 the firewall rules should *not* pertain to the instances on the same network, and this should be regulated by the specific firewall rules on the specific instance (e.g. iptables).

However, for some reason my instances -- all created in the same region & same subnet -- still seem to be subject to the firewall rules defined for the network. Since the whole point of putting them in a network is to have unfiltered traffic between them (and let that to the individual iptables rules on same instance), blowing completely open the firewall rules for the network in order to do that is..."suboptimal" (to be very polite).

Please advise on how to achieve the effect stated in the docs (if my interpretation is correct, that is).

Can provide any further details if required.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question...

After looking at the rules for the "default" network it seems that there must be a rule that explicitly allows this.

After I've done that everything is working as expected

However, a note to whomever maintains the GCE docs:

IMO this should be explicitly be noted in the docs. Assuming that this rule is implicit for **all** networks (not only for the "default" -- is really frustrating.

FWIW, HTH some poor soul that comes across this someday...;))

/Florian